on the proof of Lagrange's theorem
The usual proof uses cosets. I get that. But I want to know if this line of thinking is correct. Suppose G is a group and $|G| = 20$. Suppose H is a subgroup of G and $h \in H$ and $|H| = 6$. Now this implies $h^6 = e \implies h^{18} = e$. Now $h^{18} \in G$ and this contradicts $|G|$. Thus a subgroup of $6$ in this case cannot exist. We can generalize this. Is this correct?

Why this contradicts $|G|$? Maybe there is another element $g$ such that $g^{20}=e.$

(I think) $h \in G$ and $h^{18} = e$ contradicts that $20$ is the smallest power to which an element can be raised to get $e$. I dont know if I am right.

For example, in $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z},+)$, the generator is $[1]$ and the order of this group is $6$, but $([2])^3=[0]=e$ (i.e. the order of $h=[2]$ is $3$)

Yes, you are right, I misunderstood "The order of an element is the order of the subgroup generated by that element".

I guess I am looking for a proof by contradiction. Assume $|H| = 6$ and show a contradiction without using LT

But we can use the idea of the proof

It seems that you seek an argument based of Euler's theorem for finite groups: $g^{|G|}=e$, and its corollary: the order of $g$ divides $|G|$.
Let $h \in H$. Then $h^6=e$. Since $h^{20}=e$, we have $h^2=h^{\gcd(6,20)}=e$.
Thus, we have $h^2=e$ for all $h \in H$. This implies that $H$ is abelian.
Take $a,b \in H$ with $a\ne b$, $a\ne e$, $b\ne e$. Then $1,a,b,ab$ are different elements of $H$. Let $c \in H$ be different from those elements. Then $c,ac,bc,abc$ are different elements of $H$. This gives us 8 elements of $H$, a contradiction.

for any arbitrary H, would the same logic result in H being abelian? (and this is really where the contradiction comes out of)

@sku, The argument does not work unchanged for arbitrary $H$.

agreed. I am thinking of a claim as such: If |H| does not divide |G| then H is abelian.
